# knockout compose image src

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach, src

I have following code, and have trouble composing the src for the image.

The issue is with accessing the longitude and latitude parameters in the src, cause above I can access them to print them out.

```
<div data-bind='foreach: posts'>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><h4><span data-bind='text: Name'></span></h4></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><b>Address:</b></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10"><span data-bind='text: Address'></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        Longitude: <span data-bind='text: Longitude'></span> -  Latitude: <span data-bind='text: Latitude'></span>
                        <img data-bind="attr: {'src':  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+ Latitude+','+ Longitude+'&zoom=13&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C'+ Latitude+','+ Longitude}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: cannot find a good a way to explain it decent, but you'd have to add `()` to each observable you use for building your source url, since observables are functions. This way `data-bind="text: Longitude"`, knockoutjs is able to figure out by itself that it is handling an observable, this way `data-bind="text: Longitude + 'aribtrary text'"` it is not.

Comment: I've tried what you proposed without any luck
<img data-bind="attr: {'src':  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+ Latitude()+','+ Longitude()+'&zoom=13&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C'+ Latitude()+','+ Longitude()}" />

Comment: then you'd need to update your question with your viewmodel code, becuase [this works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/7cCZG/). So it might be something else that causing you trouble

Comment: when concatenating, use '()' to observables. `<img data-bind="attr: {'src':  'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center='+ Latitude()+','+ Longitude()+'&zoom=13&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C'+ Latitude()+','+ Longitude()}" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid calculations in the view. That's what computed observables are meant for.

For example:

```
function PostViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable('');
    self.Address = ko.observable('');
    self.Latitude = ko.observable('foo');
    self.Longitude = ko.observable('bar');

    self.MapImgSrc = ko.computed(function () {
        var la = encodeURIComponent(ko.unwrap(self.Latitude)),
            lo = encodeURIComponent(ko.unwrap(self.Longitude));

        return 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' +
               la + ',' + lo + 
               '&zoom=13&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7C' + 
               la + ',' + lo;
    });
}
```

and

```html
<div data-bind='foreach: posts'>
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12"><h4><span data-bind='text: Name'></span></h4></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><b>Address:</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10"><span data-bind='text: Address'></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                Longitude: <span data-bind='text: Longitude'></span> -
                Latitude: <span data-bind='text: Latitude'></span>
                <img data-bind="attr: {src:  MapImgSrc}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```